# Error Linq to Entities Datetime

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, datetime

I have the following code

```
var dates = query.Select(
                 x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.Date, "yyyy-MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

var minDate = dates.Min(x => x);
```

But When I execute that, I get the exception

> System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.DateTime ParseExact(System.String, System.String,
>   System.IFormatProvider)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

What am I doing wrong? And how I can fix that?

Comment: Why do you store datetime values as string in db? Would be much easier if you use proper types for your values.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek actually the db contains values of the format "yyyy-MM", but I do not have administration access to that db

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Thanks for your edit, and your interest :)

Comment: So x.Date is not actually a DateTime but a string?

Comment: @rikitikitik Thanks a lot for your comment. yes. And this is also shown at the exception error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the error is actually quite clear.  There is no translation in Linq to Entities of ParseExact to SQL.

Remember, Entity Framework, under the covers, converts the query to a SQL command or set of commands.  If EF doesn't know how to translate something, it throws this error.

One possible solution, while not terribly efficient, is to convert the IQueryable to IEnumerable, which will allow you to execute the statement.

```
var dates = query.ToList().Select(
             x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.Date, "yyyy-MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: `query.ToList()` will fetch all data from DB, not only `x.Date` value, which is important.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - Without knowing the schema, you can't assume that there are any more than one column in the table.  I give the asker credit for knowing his own schema and making appropriate changes.

Comment: Yes, I know that's a possibility. And that's why I just commented instead of downvoting :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Erik. I thank you so much! You made it work! thanks! Just upvoted. I am very happy with the solution, but just because I want to do everything really efficient, can you also come up with something that could be more effective? Once again, I thank you so much

Comment: @JimBlum - Well, in your case, if all you want is to find the earliest date, you can probably just order the column and then just take the first entry.  If you don't actually need it in a DateTime object, then you don't even need to parse it.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I am doing a lot more with the `dates`, so I guess, I can't use that. Thanks a lot

Comment: Chosen as best answer :)

Answer (score 3):

If the dates are in the DB as strings in the format "yyyy-MM", then you can do a query based on string sorting and convert the result to a DateTime:

```
var minDateString = query.Select(x => x.Date).Min();
var minDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
    minDateString, 
    "yyyy-MM", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
);
```

Many systems have relied on the natural string ordering of "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", you can just as easily rely on a subset of that ordering.

Comment: @JimBlum from comments you've made on other answers, it seems you want to do more than just get the minimum date. Could you please update your question with more details of what you need so I can provide a better answer? I often resort to a 2-step process, reduce my rows and get as much raw data as I need, then to `.ToList()` then I safely use all the non-SQL compatible calls I like on the in-memory set.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you'd have to load all your `string` representations of datatime values from DB to memory:

```
var dates = query.Select(x => x.Date).ToList();
```

and perform parsing and min as LINQ to Objects query:

```
var min = query.Min(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x, "yyyy-MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

**If** your DB was set property and `x.Date` was `DateTime` you could do:

```
var dates = query.Select(x => x.Date);
var min = dates.Min();
```

which would be translated into proper SQL query and let `MIN()` be calculated by database, so you wouldn't have to fetch all data into application memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marcin. I will try that now

Comment: ToList will work and there's nothing actually wrong with it but if you're not actually going to use it as a List then why create a List?  Arrays are more efficient than Lists so you should be calling ToArray by default and only calling ToList when you need to.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I don't see any reason why `ToArray` would be more efficient here. Maybe only a fact, that `ToArray()` would shrink allocated array when all records are loaded when `ToList()` will keep these not used space within underlying array to make additional inserts faster in future.

Comment: This gives me a syntax error `"Cannot convert lambda expression to type ulong because it is not a delegate type"`

Comment: Check now. I noticed `x => x =>` was there by accident.

Comment: Thanks. Now I get a syntax error `The best overloaded method for System.DateTime.ParseExact(string,string,IFormatProvider ) has some invalid arguments`

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - ToArray requires that there be a large enough block of contiguous memory.  That could cause out of memory exceptions if the result set is large and the heap is fragmented, even with plenty of free memory.

Comment: List does the same, because it uses array internally to store elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marcin. Upvoted, because your answer was very much helpful

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, as you say, a List uses an array internally so how can an array not be more efficient?  The List is just an unnecessary layer in between adding overhead.  Obviously it's a very small overhead and the difference will be imperceptible to the user but an imperceptible gain is no reason not to do something so simple.  It takes absolutely no extra effort to use ToArray instead of ToList and it is more efficient, however marginally, so ToArray should be used.  Do you usually create a List where only an array is needed?  If not then why here?

Comment: OK, If you care so much about that overhead, why don't you use `AsEnumerable()`? It will make even and array unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to Entities takes your LINQ query and converts it to SQL code that it then executes against the database.  That means that the code you write has to be able to be converted to SQL code.  There is no way to convert DateTime.ParseExact to SQL code, hence the exception.  You will need to evaluate a LINQ to Entities query by calling ToArray and then you can perform a second LINQ to Objects query on that and it will understand DateTime.ParseExact.

Comment: Thanks a lot jmcilhinney for you answer. However, I think your answer could be better supported if it included a piece of code :)

Answer (score -1):

Convert Date Time in your db datetime format:

```
obj.dt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc((DateTime)obj.dt, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"));
```

It`s an easy way to compare date without time. Just use the following code:

```
_DBcontext.YourModelName.AsQueryable().Where(x=> x.CREATED_DATE.Date == dt.Date).toList();
```

Comment: That's what the first comment, 8 years ago, already suggested. It doesn't answer the immediate question and in this case it wasn't even possible.