# Compare date in linq

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, datetime-comparison

I have a string 31-10-2014 wich i want to compare with a value in the database.

```
public ActionResult SearchResult(string searchDate)
{
    var bookings = from m in db.Bookings
                   select m;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchDate))
    {
        bookings = bookings.Where(s => s.Date1.CompareTo( DateTime.ParseExact(searchDate, "dd-mm-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) >= 0);
    }
    return View(bookings);
}
```

the comparing keeps failing, How should i compare an input date to a database value (i left the try catch for validating the input to be an dattime so the example is more clear)

I get the message (even without searchData):

> Linq doesn't recognise ParseExact method.

Comment: What does mean "keep failing"?

Comment: the error message will help up but i think the issue is that EF does not know how to convert that into an SQL command.

Comment: Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's trying to compile `DateTime.ParseExact` into SQL, and failing. All you need is to define a variable and put the value into that variable, then use the variable in your query:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchDate))
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(searchDate, "dd-mm-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    bookings = bookings.Where(s => s.Date1 >= dt);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what the variable `db` is.  If it's a LINQ to SQL DataContext or EF DBContext, you can't use the methods you are using on date; there is no support. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21594049/error-linq-to-entities-datetime).  There are SQL functions to work around that issue.

If you want raw SQL support for Dates, use the [EntityFunctions class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx), which lets you do date comparisions.  CompareTo is also not supported, so you'd have to use traditional greater than.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `-` instead of an `=` in your code in Line #7.

Here's the right code.

```
public ActionResult SearchResult(string searchDate)
{
    var bookings = from m in db.Bookings
                   select m;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchDate))
    {
        bookings = bookings.Where(s => s.Date1.CompareTo( DateTime.ParseExact(searchDate, "dd-mm-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) >= 0);
    }
    return View(bookings);
}
```

Comment: It won't translate into SQL anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To make it in a simpler way, try this:

```
bookings = bookings.ToList().Where(s => s.Date1.CompareTo( DateTime.ParseExact(searchDate, "dd-mm-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) >= 0);
```

Put it first in a list so that it will not take the DateTime.ParseExact as SQL statement since there's no DateTime.ParseExact in SQL.

Hope this helps